# Android Studio, Sample Code - Not working

Tags: android, android-studio

There is [sample code](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html)  on the developer site that i wish to run.

When I import as a new Android Studio project, I'm not given any ability to run the code (disabled buttons).

I attempted to copy the source files over into the shell of a new project, but i than got errors that didn't make sense. reference to duplicate declarations in source files that had nothing relating inside them.

Is there an idiots guide on how to properly use android studio, or is it just this difficult?

Answer (score 1):

In order to correctly import the project, you should follow the [Samples guide](http://developer.android.com/samples/index.html) as found in the developer docs.

> To import a downloaded project:
>
> - Unpack the downloaded project package.
> - In Android Studio, chose **File >
>   Import Project** and select the root folder of the unpacked project.
> - Android Studio may ask you to choose the type of project you are
>   importing.
> - If this is the case, make sure to choose Import project
>   from external model and select the Gradle option.

Alternatively, if the Gradle option does not work, I would attempt to use the Eclipse option.

Answer (score 0):

Open .gradle file when you import the project, not the folder of the proyect.